# Unexpected recompositions on Composables that accept lambda functions as argument

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

I have a `Composable` function that has a single `Button` that accepts lambda as an argument for `Button`'s `onClick` parameter. I define an empty function in my `ViewModel` and provide it to this `Composable`. Also in `ViewModel` there's a list, that is periodically (every second) inserted with a new item. The list is supplied to a different `Composable`, that contains a `LazyList`.
My problem is that whenever an item is added to the list, the `Composable` with a Button is recomposed, even though that function has only 1 argument -- an empty lambda function that does nothing.

Here's `MainActivity` snippet:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
  private val mainViewModel by viewModels<MainViewModel>()
  
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
      RecompositionTestTheme {
        Surface(
          modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), 
          color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
        ) {
          MainScreen(mainViewModel)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

@Composable
fun MainScreen(
  viewModel: MainViewModel = viewModel(),
) {
  Column {
    TopBar(viewModel::doNothing)
    CenterScreen(viewModel.deviceList)
  }
}

@Composable
fun TopBar(
  dummyAction: () -> Unit
) {
  Row {
    Button(onClick = dummyAction) {
      Text("Do nothing")
    }
  }
}

@Composable
fun CenterScreen(deviceList: List<DeviceData>) {
  LazyColumn {
    items(deviceList) {
      Text("$it")
    }
  }
}
```

And `MainViewModel`:

```
data class DeviceData(
  val name: String,
  var value: Int
)

class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
  
  private val _deviceList = mutableStateListOf<DeviceData>()
  val deviceList: List<DeviceData>
    get() = _deviceList.toList()
  
  init {
    // Simulating reception of data (for example, during 
    // Bluetooth LE Scan) every second.
    flow {
      while (true) {
        delay(1000L)
        emit(Unit)
      }
    }.onEach {
      _deviceList += DeviceData("", 1)
    }.launchIn(viewModelScope)
  }

  fun doNothing() {
  }
}
```

I tested recomposition with LayourManager and also by adding `println()` to the `TopBar` function. Every second, when a new item is added to the `LazyList`, the `TopBar()` and `Button` composables are recomposed, even though they shouldn't.
The `doNothing()` function initially did something, but I simplified it, because the result was the same. For example, it could clear the `_deviceList`.

The weird thing is, that if instead of a function, I define `doNothing` as a variable calling the original `doNothing` function, it suddenly behaves properly and doesn't recompose.

What I mean is the following:

```
fun doNothing() {
}

val doNothingVal: () -> Unit = {
  doNothing()
}
```

Then I call it like this:

```
TopBar(viewModel.doNothingVal)
```

So I have the following two things that I don't understand:

1. Why the original `doNothing()` function causes recompositions in the first place.

It can be used either as a lambda or as a member reference, no difference:

```
TopBar({ viewModel.doNothing() })
// or
TopBar(viewModel::doNothing)
```

2. Why using a function variable instead, doesn't cause a recomposition?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure `TopBar(viewModel::doNothing)` is causing recompositions? I don't think it's supposed to. The lambda way should cause recompositions because you're creating a new function object wrapping that call each time that code is reached. But the member reference I think should be recognized as stable.

Comment: @Tenfour04, it's very weird. I had one brief moment when method reference didn't cause recomposition (the only thing I changed in the code is the way I pass `doNothing`), but I cannot replicate it again.

Comment: I tested your code, it doesn't trigger recomposition in either way. Layout Inspector is not always correct, i also saw on Layout Inspector TopAppbar recomposition count increasing but it didn't log anything and i also use random colored borders to see recomposition visually. You should log inside SideEffect to be 100% sure that recomposition happens since SideEffect is called only after successful recomposition.

Comment: @Tenfour04 lambdas that are stable do not trigger recomposition. https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Jetpack-Compose-Tutorials/blob/master/Tutorial1-1Basics/src/main/java/com/smarttoolfactory/tutorial1_1basics/chapter4_state/Tutorial4_2_7LambdaRecomposition.kt

Comment: @Thracian I tested with `SideEffect` { println("Re!") } at the end of the `TopBar` function and I see logs every second. Here's how I reproduce it. Initially in your code pass member reference to the TopBar: `TopBar(viewModel::doNothing)`. Then fully clean project (Build -> Clean Project), rebuild it and launch it. There will be no recompositoins. Then, pass func variable `TopBar(viewModel.doNothingVal)`, build and launch. Still no recompositions. Finally, go back to passing member reference, build and launch. Now there will be recomposition every second. No way to go back, unless full clean.

Comment: I ran several tests with  ` TopBar {
            viewModel.doNothing()
        }` and in any of them i saw any logs inside `SideEffect` other than composition. If you can reproduce it as the way you described there should be something else. I run this in a new project and i  no recompositions with member reference or with lambda. I suggest you to do it in a clean project. Even if it's reproducible as you described it's something should be opened as bug because it's not expected behavior.

Comment: There is only one difference though. I replaced this `viewModel: MainViewModel = viewModel(),` with ` viewModel: MainViewModel`.

Comment: @Thracian i do it in a clean project. Only add `lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx`, `lifecycle-viewmodel-compose`, `lifecycle-runtime-compose` to the dependencies. Here's a video of recomposition log triggering: https://webmshare.com/play/O9RgY.